# How can i get the file on my local pc from vps ip with paramiko or by some other way?

Tags: python-3.x, paramiko

I have an vps ,my local pc is in the local area network.
When paramiko  installed on my local pc ,i can get file from my vps.

```
import paramiko
t = paramiko.Transport(("vps ip",22))
t.connect(username = "username", password = "key")
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
remotepath='/tmp/test.txt'
localpath='/tmp/test.txt'
sftp.get(remotepath,localpath)
```

Now the problem is ：how can i get the  file on my local pc from vps ip  with paramiko or by some other way?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? Do you mean you want to copy the file on your local pc to the vps? As in sftp.put?

Comment: no,my vps ip is x, and my local pc ip is y, how can i get the file in y from the python console (which ip is x)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may interest you : [Here](https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py)

It's a python scp module for paramiko.